# Angular Binding Not Changing Before Observable Call

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using Angular 4+, and I noticed Angular is not updating the binded value before I call Observable.subscribe() when the Observable resolves immediately (synchronously?).
In other places this works fine, because a network call delays the Observable completion long enough for the initial binding change to take effect in Angular.

https://plnkr.co/edit/LV0On7?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, VERSION} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAlertClickedNoDelay()">Call Observable Without Delay</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAlertClickedDelay()">Call Observable With Delay</button>

      <alert *ngIf="isAlertVisible()" type="success" dismissible="true" (onClose)="onAlertClose()">
          Async action successful!
      </alert>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name:string;
  private isCallComplete = false;
  isAlertVisible(): boolean {
    console.log("isAlertVisible() binding updating: ", this.isCallComplete);
    return this.isCallComplete;
  }
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

   onAlertClickedNoDelay() {
    this.isCallComplete = false;
    console.log("set isCallComplete = false");
    Observable.of("some data").subscribe(data => {
      this.isCallComplete = true;
      console.log("set isCallComplete = true");
    });
  }

   onAlertClickedDelay() {
    this.isCallComplete = false;
    console.log("set isCallComplete = false");
    Observable.of("some data").delay(0).subscribe(data => {
      this.isCallComplete = true;
      console.log("set isCallComplete = true");
    });
  }

  onAlertClose() {
    this.isCallComplete = false;
    console.log("set isCallComplete = false");
  }
}
```

Without Observable.delay(), console prints:

> set isCallComplete = false
>   set isCallComplete = true
>   isAlertVisible() binding updating:  true
>   isAlertVisible() binding updating:  true

When using Observable.delay(), console correctly prints:

> set isCallComplete = false
>   isAlertVisible() binding updating:  false
>   isAlertVisible() binding updating:  false
>   set isCallComplete = true
>   isAlertVisible() binding updating:  true
>   isAlertVisible() binding updating:  true

1) Why does Angular detect the initial property binding (isCallComplete = false) when using Observable.delay(0).subscribe() and not Observable.subscribe()?

2) What is the best solution to bind to a busy property value before a Observable.subscribe() call?

Comment: You can use one the methods suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/1009922) to trigger change detection before subscribing to the observable.

Comment: Thanks, ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() seems the best workaround. Though I hate doing that everywhere I use an isBusy property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Angular never gets the chance to check the value of `isCallComplete`.

Your Observable's subscribe callback gets executed right after it is created.

Using `delay(0)` would be the equivalent of using `setTimeout(()=>/*...*/,0)`, thus delaying the execution of the subscribe callback after the current synchronous code has executed (in this case Angular checking your component's values)

Comment: Thanks as this confirms what I was guessing was happening with change detection. To be safe, I'll let Angular know manually about the property change before the observable call.